# How to sequence a loop for 24 hours e.g. .. 22 23 00 01

Tags: bash, shell-script

I need to output a specified amount of hours only (e.g 8 hours) and shift time point according to a UTC time zone change.

The output I'd like to see is:

```
Athens     15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 (+2)
Hong_Kong  21 22 23 00 01 02 03 04 (+8)
```

I am toying with `date` command and found [this interesting code on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/1397116/190264). A lot to learn for me.
I tweaked it to my needs. However, I found a logic problem with the change of time zone: the loop keeps incrementing hours beyond 24 hours range.
So, instead of the example above, it prints:

```
Athens     15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 (+2)
Hong_Kong  21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 (+8)
```

Which is obviously wrong.

The code uses nested loops with sequencing. For the life of me, I can't figure out how I can limit the hour's range to 24 digits.

Here is a rough idea of what is going on in the author's code. How can I prevent loop from going beyond 24 hours and circle from 23 to 00?

```bash
#!/bin/bash
timezones="2" #In the actual script this is a variable generated by a provided array of cities.
workday="08 20" #This specifies the displayed range of hours e.g working hours

for tz in `seq $timezones`
do
    printf "City-$tz  " # Just a placeholder, instead of an actual city from timezone file
    timediff[$tz]=6.    # This is a simplified command. IN the actual script time difference calculated from deducting my local time from enquiring city time zone

    for h in `seq $workday` #loop hours
        do
            printf "%02d " $(($h++${timediff[$tz]}))
        done
        printf " \n" 
done
```

Output

```
%
City-1  14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26  
City-2  14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
```

P.S.
The example above doesn't show the time zone shift in the timeline. I just don't know how to execute it.

Comment: [`modular arithmetic`](https://nrich.maths.org/4350) may be the concept you're looking for.

Comment: So mm, what do you want? The times in City X corresponding to the working hours (or whatever range) of today in your local City A? Or the current time and following hours or...?

Comment: What operating system will this run on? Can we assume GNU `date` is available (this is the default on Linux)?

Answer (score 5):

Your script doesn't run because the dot in `timediff[$tz]=6.` doesn't work in Bash which only supports integer arithmetic.

Anyway, if you want the sequence to go 22, 23, 0, 1, ..., the concept is modular arithmetic, and the operator in C-like languages is `%`. E.g.

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do
    echo $(( i % 3 ))
done
```

prints `1 2 0 1 2`. With hours, you'd use `% 24`, of course. Of course the user needs to know which day the shown hours are on. E.g. this would translate from UTC+0200 to UTC+1200

```
mytz=2 othertz=12
for h in {8..16}; do
    printf "%02d ($mytz) == %02d ($othertz)\n" "$h" "$(( (h - mytz + othertz) % 24))";
done
```

giving `08 (+2) == 18 (+12)` etc.

You could also use `date` and the `TZ` environment variable to translate, if you know the correct filename for the timezone. Using GNU date here:

```
hour=08
tz=Asia/Hong_Kong
printf "local: %s\nother: %s\n" "$(date +"%F %T %Z (%z)" -d "@$ts")" "$(TZ=$tz date +"%F %T %Z (%z)" -d "@$ts")"
```

output:

```
local: 2021-12-08 08:00:00 EET (+0200)
other: 2021-12-08 14:00:00 HKT (+0800)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can get the list of actual time zones, you could do something like this (assuming GNU `date`):

```
#!/bin/bash

timezones=("Europe/Athens" "Asia/Hong_Kong");

workday="08 20" #This specifies the displayed range of hours e.g working hours

printf '%-30s' "Here"
for myHour in $(seq $workday); do
  printf '%02d ' "$myHour"
done
printf '\n'

for tz in "${timezones[@]}"; do
  printf '%-30s' "$tz"
  for myHour in $(seq $workday); do
    theirHour=$(TZ="$tz" date -d "@$(date -d "$myHour" +%s)" +%H);
    printf '%02d ' "$theirHour"
  done
  printf '\n'  
done
```

Which produces:

```
$ foo.sh
Here                          08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
Europe/Athens                 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 
Asia/Hong_Kong                16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 00 01 02 03 04
```

If you cannot get the timezones and need to work with offsets relative to your own timezone, and want the exact output you show i the question, you could try:

```
#!/bin/bash

offsets=("2" "8");
workday="08 20" #This specifies the displayed range of hours e.g working hours

for offset in "${offsets[@]}"; do
  for myHour in $(seq $workday); do
    theirHour=$(date -d "@$(date -d "$myHour + $offset hours" +%s)" +%H)
    printf '%s ' "$theirHour"  
  done
  printf '(+%s)\n' "$offset"
done
```

Which produces:

```
$ foo.sh
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 (+2)
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 00 01 02 03 04 (+8)
```

Answer (score 2):

Though there are already some good answers, I thought I'll chip in with just the small and minimal change that was needed in your code to reset the time back to 00 at the 24th hour. Just modulo 24 the result.

```
printf "%02d " $((($h++${timediff[$tz]})%24))
```

Also make sure to fix the syntax error you have and change

```
timediff[$tz]=6.
```

to

```
timediff[$tz]=6
```

Bash doesn't understand floating point arithmetic so as far as its concerned `6.` is not a valid number.

Answer (score 0):

The following `bash` script takes a number of time zones on the command line and prints the times in those zones from the current time and eight hours forward.

If the script is given a Unix timestamp as an option-argument to its `-t` option, it will use that time rather than the current time to offset from.

The script tries to figure out the local time zone and outputs that on the first line.

Running the script:

```bsh
$ ./script UTC Europe/Zurich Asia/Kabul Africa/Harare
CET            20:39  21:39  22:39  23:39  00:39  01:39  02:39  03:39  (+0100)
UTC            19:39  20:39  21:39  22:39  23:39  00:39  01:39  02:39  (+0000)
Europe/Zurich  20:39  21:39  22:39  23:39  00:39  01:39  02:39  03:39  (+0100)
Asia/Kabul     00:09  01:09  02:09  03:09  04:09  05:09  06:09  07:09  (+0430)
Africa/Harare  21:39  22:39  23:39  00:39  01:39  02:39  03:39  04:39  (+0200)
```

Using GNU `date` to fetch the timestamp for 08:00 local time (today):

```bsh
$ ./script -t "$(date -d '08:00' +%s)"  UTC Europe/Zurich Asia/Kabul Africa/Harare
CET            08:00  09:00  10:00  11:00  12:00  13:00  14:00  15:00  (+0100)
UTC            07:00  08:00  09:00  10:00  11:00  12:00  13:00  14:00  (+0000)
Europe/Zurich  08:00  09:00  10:00  11:00  12:00  13:00  14:00  15:00  (+0100)
Asia/Kabul     11:30  12:30  13:30  14:30  15:30  16:30  17:30  18:30  (+0430)
Africa/Harare  09:00  10:00  11:00  12:00  13:00  14:00  15:00  16:00  (+0200)
```

The script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

unset -v t0
while getopts t: opt; do
        case $opt in
                t)      t0=$OPTARG ;;
                *)      echo 'Error' >&2; exit 1
        esac
done
shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"

# Use current time if t0 is still unset.
if [ "${t0:+set}" != set ]; then
    printf -v t0 '%(%s)T' -1
fi

# Try to figure out local time zone.
printf -v local_zone '%(%Z)T' "$t0"

# Prepend local time zone to list if set.
set -- ${local_zone:+"$local_zone"} "$@"

export TZ

for TZ do
        {
                printf '%s\n' "$TZ"
                for (( offset = 0; offset < 8; ++offset )); do
                        printf '%(%H:%M)T\n' "$(( t0 + 3600*offset ))"
                done
                printf '(%(%z)T)\n' "$t0"
        } | paste -s -
done | column -t
```

The script makes use of `printf` with the `%(...)T` format string to format a timestamp.  This format string was introduced in `bash` release 4.2.  This allows us to use the script even on systems without GNU `date`.

By setting the `TZ` environment variable to each time zone in turn, we're able to output the timestamps in the wanted time zones.  The inner loop loops over the current time (or the given time), and eight hours forward, outputting the formatted times on separate lines.  These are then collated to full lines using `paste`, and later formatted into a table using `column`.